# How can i add new table in existing realm database?

Tags: java, android, database, realm

I am using `realm 5.0.0` I want to add new table in existing data base how can i do that?

I have tried to find out solution but I found how to edit table but don't found how can i add new Table in realm in migration.

```
Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("myrealm.realm")
                .schemaVersion(2)
                .migration(new RealmMigration() {
                    @Override
                    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
                        if (oldVersion == 0) {
                            RealmObjectSchema personSchema = realm.getSchema().get("SKUItem");
                            personSchema
                                    .removeField("created_date")
                                    .removeField("modification_date")
                                    .addField("created_date", String.class)
                                    .addField("modification_date", String.class)
                            ;
                        } if (oldVersion == 1) {
                            // Here I want to add new Table 
                        }
                    }
                })
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
// Create a new class
schema.create("NewTable")
    .addField("id", int.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
    .addField("name", String.class, FieldAttribute.INDEXED);
olderVersion++;
```

Comment: how can i add constructor for it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add "migration.create("NewTableName", value: [])" in your migrationBlock.

Example:

```
var realm: Realm?
init() {
    do {
        let configuration = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 2,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if (oldSchemaVersion == 1) {
                migration.create("ConnectedDeviceData", value: [])
            }
        })
        realm = try Realm(configuration: configuration)
    } catch {
      print("Realm Initialization Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```